# Different Possible Pairs of Binary Sequences of Length 4 and 5

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I am trying to solve the following question.

How many different binary sequence pairs are there for a 4 digit and 5 digit sequence, where the first 4 digit sequence has 2 0's and 2 1's and the second 5 digit sequence has 2 0's and 3 1's.

My thought process is as follows,

For the first sequence there is $\binom{4}{2}$ and for the second sequence there is $\binom{5}{2}$.

So I must multiply these together no? Which is
$$\frac{4!\cdot 5!}{(2)!(3)!\cdot 2! \cdot 2!} = 60$$

At this point I am not sure if I have overcounted, is this figure counting the distinct possibilities where the 4 digit sequence is first and the 5 digit sequence is second and vice versa. So should I divide by 2 in this case? I am not sure?

Answer (score 1):

No, you've done it correctly.  You haven't over-counted, because there is no way to confound a 4-bit sequence and a 5-bit sequence.  If you had, say two 5-bit sequences, then you'd have to worry about double counting, if the order didn't matter.

Choosing A and then B is the same as choosing B then A, but only if both choices are possible.  If A is to be a 4-bit sequence and B a 5-bit sequence, there is no possibility of choosing B and then A if you are choosing the 4-bit sequence first.

Comment: Thanks very much and I am very glad to know I have not over-counted. However, I do not completely understand your reasoning.  Why is there no possibility of choosing B then A if I'm choosing the 4 bit sequence first? In this case, I would still get the same result if I did $\binom{5}{2}\cdot \binom{4}{2}$ no? Why is it so that it is possible to over-count for a 5 bit sequence?

Comment: If you adopt the protocol of choosing the 4-bit sequence first, and you choose A, then B, that means that A is 4 bits and B is 5 bits.  You can't choose B first, because it has 5 bits, and you are choosing a 4-bit sequence first.